# Create a base model class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask-sqlalchemy.
I currently declare my models using:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

I want to create a base model class so I will be able to declare my models like this:

```
class MyBase(db.Model):
    pass

class MyModel(MyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Is it possible?
I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Class <class 'api.models.base.base_model.BaseModel'> does not have a __table__ or __tablename__ specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.
```

I would want to be able to put the tablename and all the column attributes inside my model and not inside my base class.

Comment: What is the purpose of an empty base class? `MyBase = db.Model` would seem to work just as well.

Comment: The base class will not be empty, I was just trying to give an example of what I was trying to do. I will add functionality to it of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your custom base model is not a real model, you need to tell SQLAlchemy that it is abstract by setting `__abstract__ = True` on the class.

```
class MyBase(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
```

Unless you are adding common functionality to this custom base, there's no point in doing this.  The empty custom base is basically equivalent to just inheriting from `db.Model` directly.